# Importing custom plugins in Airflow 2 [Cloud Composer]

Tags: python, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I have a directory structure as such:

```
airflow_dags
├── dags
│   └── hk  
│       └── hk_dag.py  
├── plugins
│   └── cse   
│       └── operators.py   
│           └── cse_to_bq.py   
└── test
   └── dags   
       └── dag_test.py
```

In the GCS bucket created by Cloud Composer, there's a plugin folder where I upload the `cse` folder.

Now in my `hk_dag.py` file if I import the plugin like this:

```
from plugins.cse.operators.cse_to_bq import CSEToBQOperator
```

and run my unit test, it passes, but in cloud composer I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'plugins'` error message.

If I import the plugin like this in my `hk_dag.py`:

```
from cse.operators.cse_to_bq import CSEToBQOperator
```

My unit test fails with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cse'` but it works fine in Cloud Composer.

How do I resolve it?

Comment: Can I assume that `operators.py` is actually a folder, and should say `operators`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Airflow 2.0 to import your plugin you just need to do it directly from the operators module.

In your case, has to be something like:

```
from operators.cse_to_bq import CSEToBQOperator
```

But before that you have to change your folder structure to:

```
airflow_dags
├── dags
│   └── hk  
│       └── hk_dag.py  
├── plugins
│   └── operators   
│       └── cse   
│           └── cse_to_bq.py 
└── test
   └── dags   
       └── dag_test.py
```

Comment: I'm hoping there is a typo in this and that it should say `from operators.cse.cse_to_bq import CSEToBQOperator`.  (Notice the extra `.cse`)  Can you please confirm this?  Also, I don't see how I can get my local `composer-dev` environment *and* the remote environment to both work, since it now seems that they need different paths because the one living in Google Storage is "ignoring" the `plugins` folder.  It's annoying that Airflow would have done this...